# Get Bean while destroying

Tags: java, spring

**Can we call getBean when destroy is getting called of a class which implements ApplicationContextAware?**

```
class Abc implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;
    MyTestClass obj = null;
    public void destroy(){
        System.out.print("Calling destroy ");
        obj = (MyTestClass)applicationContext.getBean("myTestClassObject");
        obj.showMsg(); // Calling show msg of MyTestClass.
    }
}
```

Comment: In the above example `applicationContext` is null so `applicationContext.getBean` will throw a NPE

Comment: where is setApplicationContext Method? Why you asking simply try  it

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can call that as destroy calls before end of lifecycle of the bean. Anyways, Context is going to remain after that also. Please note in question ,you not assigned actual application context object to your application context field. Without it , static instance variable will be null.

```
class Abc implements ApplicationContextAware{

private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;
MyTestClass obj = null;

 public void destroy(){
        System.out.print("Calling destroy ");
        obj = (MyTestClass)applicationContext.getBean("myTestClassObject");
        obj.showMsg(); // Calling show msg of MyTestClass.
 }

   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
      applicationContext = context;
    }  
}
```

Note, implementing `ApplicationContextAware` , does not change much in life cycle. only while intializing it passes the context object by callling `setApplicationContext`method. Apart from that you bean is standard bean.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think it will allow, since destroy is called so it will throw exception that current beans are in destruction.